# How to extract matrix with pixel rgb colors (from the entire screen), by accessing computer or gpu memory?

Tags: c++, opengl, colors, pixel, rgb

I'm working on a mini project that needs to manipulate rgb colors of pixels from the entire screen.
The solution I have come up so far is to take screenshots continuously and find the rgb colors with a bit of processing. It's fast enough but it takes a lot of cpu usage because of the screenshot part.

So, I was wondering if there is a way I can extract the data I need (in matrix form) from computer memory or gpu memory, using a C++ libary, opengl* or another approach.

I'm using windows 7 64bit, but I'd like it if the solution would be cross platform (windows/linux/mac). Also it would be nice if the solution could be implemented with C/C++/Java/Python (any of these will do).

*I did some research the past week and I don't think it's possible with opengl. However, I'm not so sure...

**EDIT** Right now I have working code in Java and Python that takes screenshots of my entire display and averages the rgb colors of pixels. In java I use processing and Robot library and in python I use PIL. 
In java I grab the image with createScreenCapture() and read the values with getRGB().
In python I grab the image with ImageGrab.grab(), load the object and read the values in tuples.

The python code as an example is this:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageGrab
import operator

#######################################
#scree resolution
width = 1920
height = 1080
step = 10
#######################################

def process(pix):
    temp = (0, 0, 0)
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, width, step):
        for j in range(0, height, step):
            temp = tuple(map(operator.add, temp, pix[i,j]))
            count += 1
    return (int(temp[0]/count), int(temp[1]/count), int(temp[2]/count))

while True:
    img=ImageGrab.grab()
    pix = img.load()
    res = process(pix)
    print(res)
```

However this code works only in Windows (because of imageGrab)...

Comment: It's not as straightforward as you'd probably like, but you can have OpenGL draw to a frame buffer object (FBO), which will then contain the pixel values that would normally have been drawn to the screen.

Comment: If you render with openGL, you can use render to texture technique, which renders the 'screen' to a texture, so you can modify the image before displaying it.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to explain what you're doing right now (i.e. a little more than just "take screenshots continously" - how exactly are you doing this?)

Comment: @JBentley Edited the 1st post. Hope this helps to understand what I'm doing :)

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thanks for the answers, but I don't want to just access data of my own application. I want to access the rgb colors of the entire display lets say (1920x1080). The screen might contain multiple windows (3rd party apps), shortcut icons, the background etc. And I want to put the rgb color values of each pixel in a matrix and read them. I'm really sorry if I wasn't very clear in my 1st post.

Comment: Ah, no, it wasn't entirely clear. While I haven't looked at the source code for PIL, my immediate guess is that substantial improvements on it would *not* be trivial, so trying to do this on your own is unlikely to accomplish much unless you're willing to put a lot of work into it.